# Run function from google script html page, not whole file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am creating a google script that will make a new google form based off of the users input in the html file.

In order to actually make the form, I need to “send a message” from the html file to the gs file.

I have tried using google.scripts.run.FUNCTIONNAME but when I do that, it appears that the entire gs file runs.

In the gs file I first create a blank form, then have a function to add questions that should be called by the html file, but it appears the html file calls the entire gs file, not just the function.

Comment: Can you share your full gs code? If "entire gs file" isn't inside a function it will always run, cause it's considered a global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you encapsulate all other code inside functions?

```
/* This code will be executed every time, including google.scripts.run.to_be_run_inside_html */
var x = 100; 

function to_be_run_inside_html(){
    /* Code will be executed by google.scripts.run.to_be_run_inside_html */
    var x = x+500;

    Logger.log(x); // would be 600
}

function to_not_be_run_inside_html(){
    var x=x+300;
    /* Code will NOT be executed by google.scripts.run.to_be_run_inside_html */
}
```